how to delete ssl from my lightsail instance?
I'm new to AWS and recently went through a practice run where I associated my Lightsail WordPress instance with SSL connected to a domain name of mine associated with SquareSpace.  That was just a random association that I created as a practice run, so I could make sure that I was familiar with the proper steps before associating my Lightsail WP instance with the end client domain name.
I deleted the AWS DNS Zone that was created as part of that process.  So now my external domain doesn't display my Lightsail WP website. But the SSL association with my Lightsail WP instance still lingers. I think ChatGPT was under the impression that deleting the DNS Zone that was created as part of that association process would delete the SSL as well. But that didn't happen.
Seems like there should be a reasonably easy way to delete the SSL association. But I get the impression that guidance doesn't appear to be in ChatGPT's wheelhouse.  Can you provide some guidance on how I could go about doing that?
